# java program that connects to oracle and get some data from it

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g

I am coding a program in java using eclipse as my IDE. It connects to a oracle database through a JDBC driver and prints out some data. The program works like a charm but the output has zeroes after ORDER DATE and SHIPDATE.

Where are they coming from and how can I remove them ?

Want to do Q1 (1) or Q2 (2) or (X) exit:

```
ORDER       ORDER DATE      SHIPDATE        COMPANY
====        ==========      ========        =======
10440       2007-02-10 00:00:00     2007-02-28 00:00:00     Save-a-lot Markets
10441       2007-02-10 00:00:00     2007-03-14 00:00:00     Old World Delicatessen
```

**This is my code :**

```
private static void doQ2(Connection conn)
    {
        try
        {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, user, password);
            conn.clearWarnings();
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from VQ2");
            System.out.print("ORDER     ORDER DATE      SHIPDATE        COMPANY\n"
                        + "====     ==========      ========        =======");
            System.out.println("");
            while(rs.next())
            {
                System.out.print(rs.getString("ORDERID"));
                System.out.print("      ");
                System.out.print(rs.getString("ORDERDATE"));
                System.out.print("      ");
                System.out.print(rs.getString("SHIPPEDDATE"));
                System.out.print("      ");
                System.out.print(rs.getString("COMPANYNAME"));
                System.out.println("");
            }
            rs.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Show us the code that retrieves the data and formats the output.

Comment: am sorry am new here and ill learn how to post my code ..

Comment: When you put code in, make sure you copy the code and click the {} symbol :)

Comment: any help with my problem here with the zeroes !??

Comment: So you are not concerned about the time and only the date correct?

Comment: yes , just the zeroes that are appearing from no where !

Comment: You could do, rs.getObject("ORDERID") and cast it into a oracle.sql.DATE. Then call http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/sql/DATE.html#toText_java_lang_String__java_lang_String_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do, rs.getObject("ORDERID") and cast it into a oracle.sql.DATE.

Then call:

[toText](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/sql/DATE.html#toText_java_lang_String__java_lang_String_)

With the format, try "YYYYmmdd"

Formats can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/sql/DATE.html#fromText_java_lang_String__java_lang_String__java_lang_String_)

Comment: oracle.sql.date orderDate = (oracle.sql.date) rs.getObject("ORDERID");

Comment: I figured it out , i just had to do this :

Comment: SELECT ORDERID, TO_CHAR (ORDERDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') ORDERDATE, COMPANYNAME FROM VQ2.... thank you sooo much for ur responses

Answer (score 0):

Just had to convert ORDERDATE and SHIPPEDDATE to_char 'YYYY-MM-DD'

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT ORDERID, TO_CHAR (ORDERDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') ORDERDATE, "
                        + "TO_CHAR (SHIPPEDDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') SHIPPEDDATE, COMPANYNAME FROM VQ2");
```